# Hide output of the previous button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I work on a program that works as a note keeper for important notes, and I'm using Tkinter. However, if I pressed a button and worked with its output, and wanted to press another button, their outputs overlapping each other.

Like in this picture:

[Overlap picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDP4r.png)

and what I want to be is:
[pressing Delete Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ggbo.png),
[Pressing adding new thing Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5meaI.png)

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("500x650")
Tn=StringVar()
In=StringVar()

#for First Button:

def exit1():
    exit()

def printt():
    Title=Tn.get()
    itemSaved=In.get()
    news="\n"+Title+": "+itemSaved
    text_file = open("Saved.txt", "a")
    text_file.write(news)

def newsaver():
    label2=Label(window,text=" The title of the saving item :",width=27,font=("arial",10,"bold"))
    label2.place(x=80,y=370)
    entry2=Entry(window,textvar=Tn)
    entry2.place(x=300,y=374)
    label3=Label(window,text=" The saved item is:",width=27,font=("arial",10,"bold"))
    label3.place(x=80,y=390)
    entry3=Entry(window,textvar=In)
    entry3.place(x=300,y=394)
    b3=Button(window,text="Done",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=printt)
    b3.place(x=150,y=450)
    b3=Button(window,text="Exit",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=exit1)
    b3.place(x=150,y=480)
#---------------------------------------------
#For Second button:

def show():
   
    f_open = open('Saved.txt', 'r')
    lines = f_open.readlines()
    hw_lists = []
    cb_vars = {}  # dict to store the BooleanVar
    for line in lines:
        index = line.find(':')
        if index >= 0:
            hw_lists.append(line[0:index])
    f_open.close()
    
    for category in hw_lists:
        var = BooleanVar()
        ch1=Checkbutton(window, text=category, variable=var,onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        
        ch1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor = W)
        cb_vars[category] = var  # store the BooleanVar
    def Del():
        lst=[]
        selected_category = [c for c in cb_vars if cb_vars[c].get()]
        a_file = open("Saved.txt", "r")
        linees = a_file.readlines()
        a_file.close()

        new_file = open("Saved.txt", "w")
        
        
        for k in linees:
            for i in selected_category:
                if not (k.startswith(i)):
                    lst.append(k)
                    
        seen = set()
        seen=set([x for x in lst if lst.count(x) > 1])
        print(seen)
        for i in seen:
            new_file.write(i)

        new_file.close()
    b4=Button(window,text="Delete",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=Del)
    b4.place(x=200,y=500) 
#---------------------------------------------------------
#For Third Button:
def SavedList():
    
    f_open = open('Saved.txt', 'r')
    lines = f_open.readlines()
    hw_lists = []
    chkvar = []
    cb_vars = {}  # dict to store the BooleanVar
    for line in lines:
        index = line.find(':')
        if index >= 0:
            hw_lists.append(line[0:index])
    f_open.close()
    chkvar_count = 0
    print(hw_lists)
    
    for category in hw_lists:
        var = BooleanVar()
        ch1=Checkbutton(window, text=category, variable=var,onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        
        ch1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor = W)
        cb_vars[category] = var  # store the BooleanVar
        
    def disp():
        
        lst=[]
        selected_category = [c for c in cb_vars if cb_vars[c].get()]
        a_file = open("Saved.txt", "r")
        linees = a_file.readlines()
        a_file.close()
        placem=450
        for k in linees:
            for i in selected_category:
                if  (k.startswith(i)):
                    label8=Label(window,text=k,width=50,font=("arial",10,"bold"))
                    label8.place(x=30,y=placem)
                    placem=placem+20
                    
    
    b5=Button(window,text="Show",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=disp)
    b5.place(x=200,y=580) 
    
#----------------------------------------------
b1=Button(window,text="Save new thing",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=newsaver)
b1.place(x=30,y=280)
b2=Button(window,text="delete saved thing",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=show)
b2.place(x=170,y=280)
b3=Button(window,text="see the list to review",width=16,bg='brown',fg='white',command=SavedList)
b3.place(x=320,y=280)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to continue using `place` manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the code for the Tk Inter Elemts like that:

```
    from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.config(padx=50, pady=20)

save_new_thing_button = Button(text="Save new thing", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
save_new_thing_button.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(0,30))

delete_saved_things_button = Button(text="Delete saved things", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
delete_saved_things_button.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(0,30))

see_list_review_button = Button(text="See the list to review", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
see_list_review_button.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(0, 30))

title_item_label = Label(text="The title of the saving item: ")
title_item_label.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=(20, 20))

saved_item_label = Label(text="The saved item is: ")
saved_item_label.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=(20, 20))

title_entry = Entry(width=30)
title_entry.grid(column=2, row=1,)
title_entry.focus()
saved_item_entry = Entry(width=30)
saved_item_entry.grid(column=2, row=2,)

checkbutton = Checkbutton(text="WiFi Password")
checkbutton.grid(column=0, row=3)

Done_button = Button(text="Done", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
Done_button.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=3)
Exit_button = Button(text="Exit", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
Exit_button.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=3)
Delete_button = Button(text="Delete", highlightthickness=0, fg="white", bg="red", width=25)
Delete_button.grid(column=1 , row=6, pady=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Now you need to give the buttons commands and you should be good to go :-)

Comment: this answer lacks quality, please add more code, explanation, example (and you have written `label2.place(` instead of `label2.grid(`)